# How will the shell expand an include in a here-doc?

Tags: shell-script, posix, here-document

I have a case of twisted shell logic to submit to you, since I have found nothing on that particular point anywhere (please accept my apologies if I missed it).
I'll try to explain the context as best I can.

I have a first `scriptA` which I expect to generate a second `scriptB` through the use of a heredoc. There are two items I want to have in this heredoc: a `my_source` file include, and some variables local to `scriptA` (for expansion within `scriptA`, that is). Here is an example:

scriptA:

```
#!/bin/sh
logfile=/path/to/my_logfile
scriptB=/path/to/my_script
cat > ${scriptB} << __EOF__
  . /path/to/my_source  #this is a shell script
  echo "Some text" | tee -a ${logfile}
__EOF__
```

My question on the snippet above is: will shell expansion on the `.` instruction (i.e. inclusion of `my_source`) occur in `scriptA` or in `scriptB`?

Bonus: is it possible to specify somehow that some *part* of the here doc should not be expanded?

*Note: I tried to be POSIX-compliant here and avoid bash specifics*

Thanks for the insights!

EDIT: Answer is that the `.` utility shall not trigger in the here-doc in `scriptA`. This is because a here-doc only performs:

> parameter expansion, command substitution, and arithmetic expansion

The `.` is a shell special built-in utility, which is not expanded (just like all shell built-ins, including bash-, ksh-, tcsh-specific (...) built-ins).

Thanks @ilkkachu for the insight.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, a here-doc is expanded mostly [like a double-quoted string](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_07_04):

> If no part of word is quoted, all lines of the here-document shall be expanded for parameter expansion, command substitution, and arithmetic expansion.

Backslashes also work to escape special characters.

The note about quoting means that something like `<<"EOF"` would prevent expanding anything within the here-doc. In your example, the reference to `${logfile}` would be expanded by the shell before passing the input to `cat`.

You could still use command substitution if you want to include the output of a command, but if all you want is that, using a pipe would also be a logical choice.

Comment: I was assuming the `.` would fall under the command substitution definition, e.g. expanded before the here-doc creation. Thanks for the quick comment!

Comment: @Meeshkah, nope. Even though it has an unusual name, it's just a builtin command (strictly speaking, a [special built-in utility](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_14), but the difference is minor).

Comment: ok I see the difference now, thank you. Can you expand on your suggestion to use a pipe in your OP? I'm not sure I get this 'choice'

Answer (score 1):

The heredoc doesn't do re-interpretation or you can say, doesn't run any commands inside it.
It just interpolates strings.

So the answer to your query is that the `source`-ing will not happen inside the heredoc.

As for the latter, you can make use of `\` i.e., backslashes to turn OFF the meaning of characters you don't want expanded by the heredoc.

Comment: OK, what would happen if I escaped the `.` command:
`\. /path/to/my_source`? Would the backslash be included in the here-doc b/c the `.` is not recognized as a command?

Comment: Nothing would happen. The \  would be found attached to the `.`  and that's it. I would urge you to consider the heredoc as a multiline variable being double quote interpolated. (unless there's a \heredoc)

Answer (score 0):

I know this is super old, but I ran across it one of my searches and wanted to correct it for others.

Here documents can use command substitution with either the backtick ` or using the usual $() notation.  So in your case you could source the my_source file using $(. ./my_source).

However, based on your description, I believe you do not really want to source the my_source file.  My interpretation of the post is that your intent is to include the content of the my_source file rather than execute the my_source file which would result in its stdout being incorporated into ScriptB.

Instead for posix compliance use command substitution with cat.

```
#!/bin/sh

logfile=my_logfile
scriptB=my_script
cat > ${scriptB} << __EOF__
  $(cat my_source)  #this is a shell script
  echo "Some text" | tee -a ${logfile}
__EOF__
```

Command substitution creates a subshell, so if you are ok with bashisms just read the whole file into a variable and then use regular parameter expansion.

#!/bin/bash

```
logfile=my_logfile
scriptB=my_script
IFS="" read -r -d '' my_source_var < my_source
cat > ${scriptB} << __EOF__
  ${my_source_var}  #this is a shell script
  echo "Some text" | tee -a ${logfile}
__EOF__
```

Comment: edit to place the hashbang in the code block

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).